# Azure Data Factory v2 - having trouble iterating through list of servers in table

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that includes a simple copy task that reads data from an SFTP source and writes to a table within a server.  I have successfully parameterized the pipeline to prompt for which server and table I want to use at runtime but I want to specify a list of server/table pairs in a table that is accessed by a lookup task for use as parameters instead of needing to manually enter the server/table each time.  For now it's only three combinations of servers and tables but that number should be able to flex as needed.

The issue I'm running into as that when I try to specify the array variable as my parameter in the lookup task within a For Each loop the pipeline fails telling me I need to specify an integer in the value array. I understand what it's telling me but it doesn't seem logical to me that I'd have to specify '0', '1','2' and so on each time.

How do I just let it iterate through the server and table pairs until there aren't any more to process?  I'm not sure of the exact syntax but there has to be a way to tell it run the pipeline once with this server and table, again with a different server and table, then again and again until no more pairs are found in the table.

Not sure if it matters but I am on the data flow preview and using ADFv2

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity#iteration-expression-language

I guess you want to access the iterate item, which is `item()` in adf expression language.

If you append a foreach activity after a look up activity, and put the output of lookup activity in `items` field in foreach activity, then `item()` means the iterate item in the lookup output.